# Neovim cmd can't find binary

Tags: neovim

I recently set up jdtls using Mason and it requires Java 17 while I still want Java11 as my default version. How can I point neovim to use the specific Java version?

On my set up, I use sdkman to manage my java version. On terminal I can use:

```
sdk use java 17.0.5-amzn
```

to change from Java 11 to Java 17. I've attempted to use Neovim cmd to execute this but it could not find sdk for some reason. On NeoVim:

```
:!sdk use java 17.0.5-amzn
```

Or even within the file:

```
vim.cmd([[!sdk use java 17.0.5-amzn]])
```

This will return me

```
/bin/bash: line 1: sdk: command not found
```

[command not found in Neovim, while usable in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WoIC.png)

I also tried:

```
:call system("sdk use java 17.0.5-amzn")
```

```
:checkhealth
```

will still return me Java11

Any thoughts on how to achieve this? I have been scratching my head all day...

Comment: Could you try to add full path to call `sdk` in `vim.cmd` ? `which sdk` gives you the full path of the binary.

Comment: I have tried that. Which sdk returns nothing, which is weird. I put in my .bash_profile:
```
source "/home/wpham/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```
So I grab the whole path, but that didn't work as I used that path to execute but it returns nothing

Comment: `.bash_profile` is only read when the shell is started in _interactive mode_, something which most likely isn't true for your setup.